# REACT rendering was empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, in my render function of a special component he return an empty result and I have nothing errors in my dev tool console. I don't understand.

So please if you have an idea.

I have this folders :

src :

- components

  - app.js
  - users_list.js
- reducers

  - reducer_users.js
- actions

index.js (contain the import of app.js)

So in my app.js I import the users_list.js (He contain only a title who say "Hello" but he return nothing)

Please look at the screenshot :
[image: userList.js]

userList.js[image]

(userList.js)

(app.js)

Comment: To answer this question, more information is needed. It would be helpful if you maybe created a small jsfiddle (here is a react-starter: https://jsfiddle.net/9bcox4ak/) with your very problem. I'd be glad to be of help then. I think the issue might be your server or whatever you're using to build this. Do you use create-react-app ? (here's another link: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

Answer (score 4):

You should start the name of your component with an uppercase letter, otherwise React will consider it as a native element and not a React component.

Comment: Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized